# Can't get frequency/channel. Code 22

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

When I log into my older laptop running Lubuntu, I get two pop-ups at login (one after the other) with this text:

```
 An error occurred. Can't get frequency/channel.  Code 22.
```

[image: Error message]

Does anyone know what the fix is for this?

Wireless has worked throughout.  This error occurs whether or not I'm using wireless, even when I have the hardware wireless switch turned off, and I'm connected over the wire.  I'm getting DHCP info and connectivity without problems from my wired connection.

After right-clicking on the network icon, I can see that it also believes that my wireless is inactive.

Comment: Question: Does your wireless work after starting up your laptop or do you need to reset it to work? It seems to be pointing to a wireless card problem when trying to connect. Might have something to do with with the type of channel/frequency the router has on it.

Comment: Spelling errors are usually trivial...but trivial to fix too, so it makes sense to report them as bugs. How was [occurred](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occurred) spelled in the error message? (It's spelled correctly, as you quoted it in the sentence.)

Comment: @belacqua i had a wireless switch on my old XPS m1530 computer to turn on/off wireless/bluetooth. Do you switch it off while the computer is on and wireless is actively connected? Like you said, it could have been trying to actively connect to wlan0 while it was on but then isn't fast enough to know it was turned off. I don't know enough about Lubuntu but does it have a network status icon which allows you to disconnect a wired or wireless connections?

Comment: Right-clicking the network icon shows that networking that wireless is disabled (every time I log in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was caused by the `rutilt` wireless pacakge.  Removing it resolved the issue.  I'm currently trying to determine whether Lubuntu installed the package -- I already have the standard Ubuntu wireless tools in place, and they work whether or not the Error in question appears, and with or without `rutilt`.